# error appears when i add anything in my controller

Tags: grails, grails-2.5

i'm using Grails 2.5.1 on Windows 7 64 bit , After generating the controllers and the views using Grails command

```
generate-all "*"
```

When i add any new lines in my controllers i get the below error :

> Compilation error: startup failed:
>       E:\Development\eclipse\TekDays\grails- app\controllers\com\tekdays\TekEventController.groovy:47: Ambiguous        expression could be a parameterless closure expression, an isolated open code block, or it may continue a previous statement;solution: Add an explicit parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to   be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}, and also either remove the previous   newline, or add an explicit semicolon ';' @ line 47, column 4.
>               {
>         ^
>       1 error

here is my controller :

```
package com.tekdays

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class TekEventController
{
def taskService // this what i added
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index(Integer max)
{
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond TekEvent.list(params), model:[tekEventInstanceCount: TekEvent.count()]
}

def show(TekEvent tekEventInstance)
{
    respond tekEventInstance
}

def create()
{
    respond new TekEvent(params)
}

@Transactional
def save(TekEvent tekEventInstance)
{
    if (tekEventInstance == null)
    {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (tekEventInstance.hasErrors())
    {
        respond tekEventInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    tekEventInstance.save flush:true
    taskService.addDefaultTasks(tekEventInstance) // this what i added
    request.withFormat
    {
        form multipartForm
        {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'tekEvent.label', default: 'TekEvent'), tekEventInstance.id])
            redirect tekEventInstance
        }
        '*' { respond tekEventInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(TekEvent tekEventInstance)
{
    respond tekEventInstance
}

@Transactional
def update(TekEvent tekEventInstance)
{
    if (tekEventInstance == null)
    {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (tekEventInstance.hasErrors())
    {
        respond tekEventInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    tekEventInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat
    {
        form multipartForm
        {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'TekEvent.label', default: 'TekEvent'), tekEventInstance.id])
            redirect tekEventInstance
        }
        '*'
        {
            respond tekEventInstance, [status: OK]
        }
    }
}

@Transactional
def delete(TekEvent tekEventInstance)
{

    if (tekEventInstance == null)
    {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    tekEventInstance.delete flush:true

    request.withFormat
    {
        form multipartForm
        {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'TekEvent.label', default: 'TekEvent'), tekEventInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'
        {
            render status: NO_CONTENT
        }
    }
}

protected void notFound()
{
    request.withFormat
    {
        form multipartForm
        {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'tekEvent.label', default: 'TekEvent'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'
        {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any advice to solve this error ? 
Thanks

Comment: When you add any new lines? Have you done a grails clean?

In your example, you're attempting to inject TaskService into your class. Have you tried a normal line like a logging print or something? How do you know it is *any* line?

Comment: no i didn't do any clean , i tried to use println , but getting the same error, even after commenting what i did the error still exists , even when you try to make spaces between lines i get this error !!

Comment: Alright. Then do a grails clean first, and make sure you've wiped out any old data. Then if these are just the normal, scaffolded views / controllers, delete all of them and regenerate them.

Comment: i just did clean now , but it's not helping , the only way to get rid of this error is to delete the controller and regenerate it again  but if you tried to add anything in it i'll get the same error again , very weird thing i don;t what is causing this ..

Comment: Can you push your code to github repo for others to investigate if something went wrong in your workspace?

Comment: nothing in my code it's only one domain and a controller and i posted the controller here .. do you see anything wrong in the controller ?